# Is there something you can do with bind that you can not do with on?

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

The [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) to jQuery's `bind` method states that:

> ```
> As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document.
> ```

Does that mean that the `bind` method will eventually get deprecated, or is there a case where you can achieve something only using the `bind` method, and not the `on` method?

Comment: AFAIK there is nothing that can be done with `.bind()` which is not possible in `.on()`

Comment: i think its important to mention that not everything done with .on can be done with .bind like calling .on on elements getted by ajax.    "on" have extra param selector ".on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler(eventObject) )"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In jquery source code:

```
bind: function( types, data, fn ) {
        return this.on( types, null, data, fn );
    },
```

So bind() method is using internally .on() method.

Usually, when a method is not the preferred one, this could indicate first stage before being deprecated and then removed on later version.

So to answer your question: No, there is nothing `.bind()` can do that `.on()` cannot, use `.on()` method.

Comment: @AlexKneller ya, .on() allow to use delegation, .bind() doesn't.

Comment: @JamesMontagne could you elaborate on this?

Comment: I actually found it within the documentation of `on` and removed my comment.  While `on` doesn't have a signature which explicitly mentions `preventBubble` (as bind does), it does mention that `false` can be passed in place of a callback.

Comment: @JamesMontagne i've never taking much attention to that, this is an usefull shorthand, thx.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing you can do with `bind` that cant' be done with `on`.  That doesn't necessarily mean it will be deprecated though.  This is also true for `click`, `change`, etc.  `on` can replace many other parts of the jquery library but that's not a reason to get rid of them.  The alternatives are shorter and in some cases arguably more readable.

I suppose the reason for having both is that `bind` specifically does not do event delegation whereas `on` can be used with or without delegation.  I dont' think anyone other than the jquery team themselves will be able to tell you if it will be deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is nothing that can be done with `.bind()` which is not possible in `.on()`

From docs of [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

> The .on() method attaches event handlers to the currently selected set
>   of elements in the jQuery object. As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method
>   provides all functionality required for attaching event handlers. For
>   help in converting from older jQuery event methods, see [.bind()](http://api.jquery.com/bind/), 
>   [.delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/), and [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/).